# Disable notification when logging in with apple watch

Tags: macos, apple-watch

OSX Sierra added the ability to login to your mac via a paired Apple Watch instead of typing a password.  This is a great feature, but every time I log in it sends a notification to the Apple Watch, which can be annoying (especially since the notification tone is exactly the same as the one used for actual notifications).  Is there any way to disable that notification, or at least tun off the sound for that one without completely muting the watch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to disable the sound without disabling all notification sounds, as you've already discovered.

I would recommend leaving feedback for [Apple here](http://www.apple.com/feedback/watch.html) and let them know what new features you'd like to have added to the watch.  I already left my feedback for this option but it would help to have others do the same thing.